# VBA to Clear a content of a cell if another cell is changed or cleared while KEEPING conditional formatting rules

Tags: vba, excel

I have googled this issue, but I can't seem to find the right answer anywhere. I'm new to VBA so excuse me if my question sounds dumb.

I have a VBA code that is found in the worksheet section.

*When Cell E13 is changed or cleared, cell Q13 is cleared. Similarly, if E14 is changed or cleared, cell Q14 is cleared. This goes all the way down to row number 499.* This also applied to E3 and Q3.
Please note that Q3 has conditional formatting rules that are different than the conditional formatting rules of Q13-Q499. Also, Q13-Q499 share the same conditional formatting rules.

However, **in rows 13-499**, when a cell in column E, say E20, is cleared, this changes the conditional formatting rule of its relative cell in column Q, which is Q20. For some reason, clearing E20 seems to apply to Q20 the conditional formatting rule of Q3.

Could anyone help me adjust the code so it does what it currently does, but also keeps my conditional formatting rules?

This might help. Here are the conditional formatting rules that I have in column Q.

**Q3:**
Q3 default fill color is "Blue" and default borders is "All Borders".
1) IF E3="Company", change the fill color of Q3  to "White" and keep borders as "All Borders".
2) If Q3<>"Company", keep fill color as "Blue" and change the borders to "Left Border" only.

**Q13-Q499**
Q13-Q499's default fill color is "White" and default borders is "All Borders".
1) If Q13-Q499="Company", keep fill color as "White" and keep borders as "All borders".
1) IF Q13-Q499<>"Company", change the fill color of Q13-Q499  to "Grey" and change borders to both "Left & Right Borders".

The VBA code that I am using is as the following. It is pasted in the worksheet section:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = 5 Then
            Rem Clear Columns Q
            .Cells.Offset(, 12).ClearContents

            Rem Enable Events after changes
            Application.EnableEvents = 1

          End If: End With
          End If
          End Sub
```

I think I just figured out the problem. I have a Sub Copyrow() code pasted in the module. It is used to copy contents of a group of cells into the last non-blank row of my spreadsheet when a button is clicked.Since cell Q3 has a conditional formatting rule that changes its color, it seems to be copying the conditional formatting of Q3 too. Could you please fix my code, so that only when it comes to copying Q3, that the code only 'paste speacial' VALUES instead of everything. Here is my Module code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

' define which worksheet to work on, i.e. replace Sheet1 with the name of 
your sheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1. Clients Details")

' determine the last row with content in column D and add one
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' copy some cells into their ranges
ws.Range("D3:F3").Copy ws.Range("D" & lRow)
ws.[D1].Select

' combine G3, H3, I3, J3 and copy into column E, next empty row
ws.Range("G" & lRow) = ws.[G3] & " " & ws.[H3] & ", " & ws.[I3] & " " & ws.
[J3] & " "

' copy the other cells into their ranges
ws.Range("K3:P3").Copy ws.Range("K" & lRow)
ws.[K1].Select

' combine G3 & H3
ws.Range("Z" & lRow) = ws.[G3] & " " & ws.[H3]

' combine I3, J3
ws.Range("AA" & lRow) = ws.[I3] & "       " & ws.[J3]


' copy Q3 into column Q only, if Q3 = "Company"
If Worksheets("1. Clients Details").Range("E3").Value = "Company" Then
ws.Range("Q3").Copy ws.Range("Q" & lRow)


End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see anything there which would affect conditional formatting.

Comment: Excel has many automated self-corrections for conditional formatting, all trying to guess what you want. Therefore you should apply CF only after you make no more changes to the sheet design. In a sheet where rows are added, even if only at the end, I would not recommend to use CF at all unless you can reset it entirely using VBA after each change, in which case it is easier to apply the formatting you want rather than asking Excel to do it for you. Anyway, look for the fault in CF, not in your code.

Comment: Hi guys.
Thanks for your comments. 
I did check my formulas as per your suggestion Variatus, and I made some changes but still no luck. However, when I changed the VBA code, it did work. I'll post the new macro in an answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Oh it's still doing the same thing again. I thought I had it fixed. Sorry

Comment: I just figured our the problem. I have a Sub Copyrow() code pasted in the module.

Comment: Hi Variatus and Tim and all users who can help, 
Could you please help me fix my code as per my updated question.
Many thanks

Comment: @Variatus could you both please help me if you can

Comment: @TimWilliams could you both please help me if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line of code `ws.Range("Q3").Copy ws.Range("Q" & lRow)`, near the bottom of your `CopyRow` procedure, with this line:

`ws.Range("Q" & lRow).Value = ws.Range("Q3").Value'

Comment: I have no idea how this change works, but it did the work. Thank you so much Variatus. You made my day!!

Comment: A cell is a `Range` which has many, many properties. When you copy a cell and make another cell just like it the other cell will inherit all the many properties, such as font, font size and font colour, back colour, frame and frame colour and more. The code that helped you just takes one property of Q3 and assigns it to the property of the same name of the target all. None of the other properties are touched. It may help you to realise that the `Value` property may be different from the `Formula` property. Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks Varitaus! Good stuff :)

Comment: @Varitaus. Hi again Variatus. Can I be a pain and ask you to adjust the above code for me again, particularly this part:

' combine G3, H3, I3, J3 and copy into column E, next empty row
ws.Range("G" & lRow) = ws.[G3] & " " & ws.[H3] & ", " & ws.[I3] & " " & ws.
[J3] & " "

Comment: If G3, H3, I3 and J3 are left blank, and the button is clicked to copy it into the last row of J. This seems to make the cell in J not blank, even though it's actually blank (I think it's because of the " " in the code). 

The reason this is bugging me is because I have a conditional formula in all cells in column D to be highlighted yellow if J is not blank. (i.e. <>"").

Comment: I shall be glad to help you but this forum is a public space intended to help more than one person at a time. We try to keep correspondence focused so that onlookers can benefit from it too, should they have similar problems. Therefore please formulate your request as a new question. I am sure someone will be glad to help you, perhaps even faster than I can be. Anyway, if I come across your question I shall be happy to attend to it.